# MVC action result in slickgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

I am new to use slickgrid.

I want to know if anyone can help with returning actionresult or jsonresult to slickgrid. How can we do that?

Comment: I'm sure there are hundreds of examples on google like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365223/Using-a-SlickGrid-within-an-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Applicat).

Comment: can you give some links?

Comment: errr.. I did - but here it is again! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365223/Using-a-SlickGrid-within-an-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Applicat

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to return your model to the slickgrid as a JsonResult as follows:

```
return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YOUR_MODEL_INSTANCE));
```

Have a look at http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx